# Weak convergence of orthonormal vectors

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Hi guys I am tring to show if $(e_n)$ be a sequence of orthonormal vectors in a Hilbert space then $e_n \rightarrow 0$ weakly i.e $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \langle e_n,y\rangle = \langle 0,y\rangle$ for all $y$.

My work
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }  |\langle e_n,y\rangle - \langle 0,y\rangle| = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }  | \langle e_n,y\rangle |$

But I am having a hard time saying that $\langle e_n,y\rangle =0$ as $n$ grows. I see on one side that we have by orthogonality that $\langle e_i,e_j\rangle =0$, but I do not see how to use that directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Bessel's inequality, the sequence $\{\langle e_n,y\rangle\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is square-summable and thus infinitesimal.